# monaco editor theme can not be changed dynamically

Tags: monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

I want to update monaco editor theme on the fly, but I found it does not work:

```
this.editorOptions = {
                ...this.editorOptions,
                readOnly: true, // this.readOnly,
                value: this.code,
                language: 'java',
                theme: 'vs'
            };
            this.currentEditor.updateOptions(this.editorOptions);
```

If I change the readOnly, it worked fine, but theme is NOT updated at all.

the create logic is like this:

```
this.editorOptions = {
                ...this.editorOptions,
                readOnly: this.readOnly,
                value: this.code,
                language: this.updatedType.toLowerCase(),
                //theme: 'vs-dark'
                theme: t === 'light' ? 'dv-light-theme' : 'dv-dark-theme'
            };
            this.currentEditor = monaco.editor.create(this._editorContainer.nativeElement, this.editorOptions);
```

Please help and show how you can update the theme on the fly dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

I just learned from https://blog.expo.dev/building-a-code-editor-with-monaco-f84b3a06deaf that to set the theme you call `monaco.editor.setTheme('<theme-name>')`. I was incorrectly calling `setTheme` on my editor instance.